# problem with textbox TextChanged inside userControl (C# code to vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, textbox, user-controls, c#-to-vb.net

I'm trying to create a custom textbox with a userControl, my problem lies in the part of setting the default event of the userControl to handle the textChanged of the textbox. I currently have the userControl with only one textbox.

In c # I have this code that works perfectly (UserControl3.cs file):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace custom_controls
{
    [DefaultEvent("_TextChanged")]
    public partial class UserControl3 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public event EventHandler _TextChanged;

        private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_TextChanged != null)
            {
                _TextChanged.Invoke(sender, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I have not been able to translate it correctly to vb.net where I need the control. Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

This is the code resulting from the conversion from C # to VB.net:

```vb
<DefaultEvent("_TextChanged")>
Public Class UserControl3

Public Event _TextChanged As EventHandler

    Private Sub textBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles textBox1.TextChanged
        If _TextChanged IsNot Nothing Then 'error here: _TextChanged 
            _TextChanged.Invoke(sender, e) 'error here: _TextChanged 
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Error image:

[image]

Comment: Yes I know it is C #, I am trying to bring it to vb.net code. But it gives me this error:  'Public Event _TextChanged As EventHandler' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.

Comment: Sorry, I was editing my question to include the resulting code part in visual basic, but my native language is not English so it takes a little longer. Excuse me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't raise events the same way in vb and c#. vb has a keyword `RaiseEvent` to do that

```vb
<DefaultEvent("_TextChanged")>
Public Class UserControl3

    Public Event _TextChanged As EventHandler

    Private Sub textBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles textBox1.TextChanged
        RaiseEvent _TextChanged(sender, e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Excellent, that solves my problem. Thank you very much, both to you and to the others who took the time to comment on my question.